# How to use vba to use formula to insert cell contents into a chart textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA to create a clustered bar chart. One of the features that I need is right-aligned Y-axis labels. Unfortunately this does not appear to be possible and (as I understand it) the only way to change the alignment is to not show the Y-axis labels and insert text boxes. I need to use a formula to populate the text box with the cell that contains the Y-axis label, but I keep getting an error when trying to do this.

I used the record macro feature to generate code that I cleaned up a little bit to yield:

```
'Y axis label corresponding to cell A12 
co.Chart.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 35, 225, 30).Select
co.Chart.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 2")).Select
Selection.Formula = "='Figure 1'!R12C1"
```

My macro fails on the last line "Selection.Formula..." and the error message returned is "Unable to set the Formula property of the TextBox class".  Any suggestions for the code i need to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
Dim TB, cht

Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart

Set TB = cht.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 10, 10, 80, 15)

TB.OLEFormat.Object.Formula = "=A12"
```

Don't think there's a `FormulaR1C1` property you can use